# Quite confused about this code snippet return types with & without =

Tags: scala, closures, equals-operator

```
object A extends App {

def closure1(x:Int) = {
  object O {
   def getX = x
   def add(y:Int) = x+y
  }
  val foo = O
  foo
}

def closure2(x:Int) {
  object O {
   def getX = x
   def add(y:Int) = x+y
  }
  val foo = O
  foo
}

println(closure1(4).getClass)
println(closure2(4).getClass)
}

result:
 $scala A
 class A$O$3$
 void
```

1. Why are the return types different ?
2. I really don't care about the return types. I want to call getX and add - I want to do something like closure1(4).getX - this is illegal. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scala has a shorthand notation for code that doesn't return any interesting value: omit the `=` sign.  In Java, this would return `void`, i.e. nothing at all; but in Scala it's actually `()`, the only member of the type called `Unit`.  Either way, it's the same: nothing or a meaningless placeholder.

The reason you want a meaningless placeholder is that when you write generic code you'd rather not have to handle the cases of something vs. nothing differently.

Anyway:

```
def f(): Unit = println("Hi")
```

is a function that explicitly returns only the content-free `()` value (which is what `println` returns also).  And the shorthand is

```
def f() { println("Hi") }
```

Now there's one sneaky addition which is that in Scala, as with many C-derived languages, you're allowed to just throw away the return value from whatever you do.  And when you throw it away, all that's left is `()`.  Scala will warn you on `closure2` that you are doing something suspicious:

```
<console>:16: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position
you may be omitting necessary parentheses
         foo
         ^
defined module A
```

but will still let you do it (as it is historically expected that this will work).

So, to summarize:

```
def f {}
```

is a method that returns only the content-free placeholder `()`.  If you write it out in full the syntax would be

```
def f: Unit = {}
```

and when you try to return a value of the wrong type, instead of complaining it throws away the value and gives you type `Unit`, but typically emits a warning:

```
def f: Unit = 5
def f { 5 }
```

(Note that opinion is mostly against the short form these days (these days being 2.10-is-stable), in large part because in the absence of a clear explanation of the difference, new users often omit `=` without realizing it and then wonder why things don't work.  So in the future (2.11 or 2.12 for deprecation?) the `def f {}` form may not work.)

If you actually want a return value--because, for example, you want to return your object `O` (which you can do directly without first assigning it to `foo`, by the way), make sure you include `=`:

```
def f = { object O { def g = 5 }; O }

scala> f.g
res0: Int = 5
```

(Hint: the compiler will complain at you that you're using structural types here.  You're better of with `trait HasG { def g: Int }` and then `object O extends HasG`; otherwise Scala actually uses reflection to call `f.g` for some rationale that I've never quite been able to follow.)

Comment: Thanks. I was more interested in getting the getX and add to work. But user Shadowlands answered that part ( though for some reason he deleted his answer! )

Comment: @kr - I added that into my answer more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I think Rex has explained the reason, you omitted the `=` when define `closure2`, which make Scala compiler think you'd like to return nothing, even though you intend to return `foo`.

```
scala> def closure3(x: Int) {
     |   object O {
     |     def getX = x
     |     def add(y: Int) = x + y
     |   }
     |   val foo = O
     |   foo
     | }
<console>:17: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
         foo
         ^
closure3: (x: Int)Unit
```

Note the return type of `closure3` is `Unit`

```
scala> def closure4(x: Int) = {
     |   object O {
     |     def getX = x
     |     def add(y: Int) = x + y
     |   }
     |   O
     | }
closure4: (x: Int)Object{def getX: Int; def add(y: Int): Int}

scala> closure3(2)
```

`closure3(2)` return nothing, so you can not call `getX`

```
scala> closure4(2)
res10: Object{def getX: Int; def add(y: Int): Int} = O$2$@a4920bc
```